# I was indirectly fired due to false accusations

Tags: termination

I was wrongly accused of theft, by my collegue and close friend (she **allowed** me to use something of hers). I was fired from my job and not given a chance to explain myself, and prove myself innocent. My mum got me this job, as she also works there. I got fired through my mum telling me, but I was not directly contacted, and I was simply removed from all group chats. I have not been directly contacted by my boss or from anyone from my workplace. I struggle with severe adhd, but this has barely affected my work, and if I struggle, I always ask for help.

What should I do to resolve this situation?

Comment: And... your question is? What is the thing we can help with?

Comment: my question is what should i do?

Comment: probably look for another job?

Comment: @ja.br25 - Reach out to your supervisor requesting your last pay check.

Comment: "by my colleague and close friend. She allowed me to use something of hers. I was fired from my job and not given a chance to explain myself, and prove myself innocent." Did your colleague and close friend accuse you? Why would they lie? Or was it someone else who accused you? If it's your word against someone else's, proving your innocence can be very difficult. What proof do you have?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It depends a lot on the jurisdiction. In my opinion, do not initiate anything legally, because that would threat the job of also your mother. Just silently leave. The situation has also the indirect meaning that they likely won't fire your mother.

Most importantly, you must find a job which is already independent of your mother. Your situation is something what a lot of people, in a good job, only would want, but they can not have ever. You have a mother. That is the good side of the story.

The bad thing is that you are clearly on the entry side of the job market and things are not going to be really fun for you.

Don't try to defend yourself with your ADHD. No one will care it. You must get your job among other people without ADHD, and you must work well there.

So, do not whine. *Get your next job, now*. Have a CV and apply for at least 10 places. And watch the results.